# Showing given representation is summand by averaging

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

This problem is from Artin 1st edition 9.2.2.

Problem : Let $\rho$ be the standard three-dimensional representation of T, and let $\rho'$ be the permutation representaion obtained from the action of T on the four vertices. Prove by averaging that $\rho$ is a summand of $\rho'$.
(T is tetrahedral group)

Attempt : I know that $\rho'$ = $\rho \oplus \rho_1 $ 
( $\rho_1$ is trivial representation of T)
by investigating the character of $\rho'$, but I don't know how to show $\rho'$ is direct sum of $\rho$ and $\rho_1 $ by '**averaging**'.

Thank in advance.